# Resolver en una api rest, una petición de borrado de registro según el valor de DOS campos de una tabla

Tags: nodejs, api

El siguiente código resuelve una petición de borrado de registro en el back-end (api rest node). En él: gasto es el nombre de una tabla MySQL, codgas es el nombre del campo por cuyo valor se peticiona el borrado desde el front-end. La duda: ¿cómo sería el código para atender a la petición de borrado, cuando debe hacerse según el valor de DOS campos recibidos desde el front-end, sean estos codgas y nomgas?.

```
app.delete('/api/gasto/:codgas',(req,res)=>{
    conexion.query('DELETE FROM gasto WHERE codgas = ?',[req.params.codgas],(error,filas)=>{
        if(error){
            throw error
        } else {
            res.send(filas)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

La repuesta a la consulta es la que sigue, donde ycodgas es una variable que contiene el valor del campo codgas que se desea pasar en la petición. Cabe aclarar que, filtrar por más de un campo, requiere las consecuentes adecuaciones en el front-end:

```
 fetch(url,{
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       codsgas: id,
       codgas: ycodgas
    })
 })
 //promesas:
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(()=>location.reload())
```